# write xml texts in html page in java

Tags: html

Im creating an html page from a java code by adding Strings line by line.
Those strings have xml tags within them and they are getting eliminated when I open it from a browser.Is there any html tag that helps me retain the original value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

replace `<` by `&lt;` and `>` by `&gt;`